# give an example of a sequence such that the set of limit points of the set of their limit points is a countable set

Tags: calculus

the problem here is that I don´t understand the question! so, can you help me understand it? I know my question is kind of silly but I would really appreciate your help :)

Comment: Should "the set of limit points of the set of their limit points" be "the set of its (subsequential) limit points"?  In either case, I suggest trying to come up with a sequence whose set of subsequential limit points is countable.

Comment: my teacher sent us the problem by mail and that was the question, maybe he didn´t write it well :/

Comment: It works either way, actually.  And you build up to what your teacher is asking of you by first trying to do what I suggested.  Rather than get limits of limits is countable, just try to get a sequence whose limit points are countable.  Upon success, you should then be able to use the same idea to get the final answer.  This relies on countable unions and/or products of countable sets still being countable, so you know.

Comment: What is about taking any countable set with the indiscrete topology and an arbitrary sequence ?

Comment: If the question allows arbitrary topological spaces, then yes, that's a clever and simple way to do it.  You can do it in the real numbers with the usual metric, though.

Answer (score 1):

As it stands, I have this interpretation.

Let $(x_{n})$ sequence and let $A$ be the set of its limit points. Then $A \subset \mathbb{R}$ (or whereever you want to take your sequence). Then, let $B$ be the set of limit points of $A$. Now find a sequence such that this set $B$ is countable.

**P.S.:** Since you only asked to explain the question, I am not giving an  answer. The answer should be obvious though.

Comment: I think your interpretation is correct, thanks a lot :D I´ll work on the problem

Comment: I have a doubt: I have a sequence that has a set of countable limit points(which is A), and then I have another sequence that sends the  elements of A to another set of countable limit points(which is B) so I have to sequences but how can I put them together so I get one sequence?

Comment: Could you write explicit sequences?

Comment: the problem here is that I have a piecewise sequence but is as follows: 2,2,4,2,4,6,2,4,6,8,...(this is A) so this sequence goes from natural numbers to even numbers, and my other sequence is as follows: 1,1,2,1,2,3,1,2,3,4,...(this is B) so this sequence goes from even numbers to natural numbers so I have two sequences with countable limit points but I don´t know if I have to put them together

Comment: $B$ is supposed to be the set of limit points of $A$. How do you get this $B$ from your $A$. And as for the answer, have you given a thought to constant sequences?